# Pronunciation of 对 and 水

Tags: pronunciation, pinyin

对 (duì) sounds to my ears more like /duei/. Similarly with 水 (shuǐ) /ʂuei/. Am I mishearing, or am I misunderstanding how Pinyin is supposed to be pronounced? Or is this a dialectal variant?

Comment: You are correct. If you know zhuyin and convert zhuyin of 水, 對, 劉 to pinyin, they should look like shuei, duei, liou. The rule of pinyin dictates e and o be dropped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After [...] a consonant, *iou, **uei**,* and *uen* are simplified as *iu, **ui**,* and *un*, which do not represent the actual pronunciation.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin#Letters

This spelling seems to have been inherited from the earlier [Latinxua Sin Wenz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latinxua_Sin_Wenz#Finals), itself following the use in Wade-Giles. Such simplifications were likely used since [wi] is an allophone of [wei]:

> In SC [wi] is a variant of [wəi]... SC does not make use of such contrasts as [wi] vs. [wəi], or [ji] vs. [i], which English does (consider *we* vs. *way*, and *yeast* vs. *east*).

- A Phonology of Standard Chinese

---

**Related questions:**

> Then we also have sounds that are there but simply left out, such as -ui actually being pronounced -uei (水, 对, 贵) and -iu actually being pronounced -iou (六，休，牛).

- [Is pinyin an accurate pronunciation guide?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/42156/24946)
- [Why is it written LIU in Pinyin, when there's clearly an O sound?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/993/24946)
- [Are there rules about the differences between pinyin spelling and pronunciation?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/9645/24946)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%E6%B0%B4

[image]

Most pronunciation you can find here. if not, try to searh the word you want to search +  `发音`